# Odoo15 | Uncaught Promise Error > deserializeDateTime

Tags: javascript, python, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, odoo-15

I've been developing some modules that extend Sale, Inventory, and MRP (manufacturing) and have been getting this error on occasion.

I've tried clearing my browser's cache but that hasn't worked to address the bug.

As a temporary fix I'll drop my db, create a new one with the same name and then load the modules, but that's not sustainable long term.

Any suggestions on why this issue pops up or how to fix it are greatly appreciated!

````
Uncaught Promise > deserializeDateTime is not a function
TypeError: deserializeDateTime is not a function
    at new ExpirationPanel (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/138-5429130/web.assets_backend.min.js:9992:157)
    at QWeb.eval (eval at _compile (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/97-5c5a31b/web.assets_common.min.js:1016:178), <anonymous>:34:16)
    at QWeb.fn (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/97-5c5a31b/web.assets_common.min.js:998:173)
    at QWeb.render (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/97-5c5a31b/web.assets_common.min.js:1005:20)
    at HomeMenu.__render (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/97-5c5a31b/web.assets_common.min.js:1334:33)
    at HomeMenu.__prepareAndRender (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/97-5c5a31b/web.assets_common.min.js:1332:29)```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The strange thing is that the error wasn't the result of my code, because it isn't an issue after I drop the db and recreate it. My guess is that the error popped up because I was editing a model in a separate buffer while the server was running, but I'm 100% not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think I found a temporary solution.
After looking for the deserializeDateTime function on the Odoo repository and enterprise I was able to find where it caused the error.

You have to delete database.expiration_date in ir.config_parameter (Menu technical > system params )
which allows to pass in the else here :

```
let expirationDate;
if (this.enterprise.expirationDate) {
    expirationDate = deserializeDateTime(this.enterprise.expirationDate);
} else {
    // If no date found, assume 1 month and hope for the best
    expirationDate = DateTime.utc().plus({ days: 30 });
}
```

I think I should send the error up to get more explanations...

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error with Official Odoo docker
the error occurs when I install the Billing application...

I am just starting to develop custom modules so for the moment there is very little code and customs.
I will try without custom module to see if the error appears too.